# What are the factors that affect CUDA kernels launch time

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I have a set of CUDA kernels. Each kernel completes its job in less than 10 microsec, however, its launch time is 50-70 microsec. I am suspecting the use of texture memory might be the reason, since it is used in my kernels.

Are there any recommendations to reduce the launch time of CUDA kernels? In general, what are the factors that affect the kernel launch time?

Comment: Are you sure you want to reduce launch time, or just reduce the ratio of launch time to compute time?

Comment: I need to minimize the overall execution time to get the job done.

Comment: Related: CUDA context creation may take longer if code was not compiled for native GPU architecture. It is likely only relevant for the first kernel though.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the overall launch time by launching fewer kernels; e.g. if you launch several kernels in sequence, you could write a new single kernel that does all of that work in a single launch.

From the very little bit of context currently in the question, I suspect this is your problem; you are doing too little work per kernel.

(my next guess is an error in benchmark; i.e. the times aren't for what you think they are)

Comment: I am doing too little work per kernel, that true. But if I combine all the kernels in one, the code would look extremely ugly and more difficult to maintain. More importantly, depending on the job, I call a subset of the kernels.
Lastly, do you have an idea about the factors that affect the kernel launch time?

Comment: I am using nsight profiler to have an impression what is going on. The launch time dominates the kernel execution time as mentioned above.

Comment: Make your kernels into device functions and call them from one big kernel. It should not change code structure too much, unless you are doing something ugly already. Look at the parameters. Maybe some of these kernels can be merged and optimized? If you insist on small short running kernels than it may be that your problem (or current solution) simply is not a good fit for massively parallel devices.

Comment: @caesar: There could still be a problem with the benchmark; e.g. there is the common downfall of writing the benchmark code so that what you're trying to time gets optimized away and the profiler is basically telling you the cost of a no-op. (I mention this because it is not an uncommon problem)